# Need RegEx to filter dataset according to specific position in string

Tags: sql, regex

Want to filter dataset with SQL query using RegEx to filter entries based on the time (hour) e.g. 19:XX or 09:XX. The hour part of the string would be in position 12 and 13.

Checked a few other questions and articles, but I'm very new to this and can't figure it out. Don't know which SQL database it is, but I work with it on Google BigQuery.Thanks for your help!

[Screenshot of data entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaodo.png)

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Don't treat date/time values as *strings*.  They should be stored in the internal format for your database.

Comment: Please tell us the database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.), and also include some sample data.  What Gordon already said.

Comment: Hey, just added a screenshot with some sample data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to access the hour in a date/time is:

```
where extract(hour from timecol) = 19
```

Not all databases support extract.  All should have something similar.

Comment: does this work with the date as string format as well?

Comment: @LukasPeherstorfer . . . Probably not, but that depends on the database.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately...

Query:

SELECT created_at, text
FROM [pierangelo-training.leading_social_practicum.Vegan_tweets_2018]
WHERE text is not null and extract(hour from created_at) = 19

Error Message:
Encountered " "FROM" "from "" at line 3, column 41. Was expecting: ")" ...